# Conditional break point on attributes in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints

I'm trying to figure out how to setup a more complex break point in my code.
I would like to make a break on specific values (e.g. break when first field of my struct is equal to 42)

```
struct SpecificKey
{
    int myFirstField;
    int mySecondField;
};

int Get(const SpecificKey& key)
{
    // <--- set conditional break point if key.myFirstField==42
    //
    // Look for value somewhere...
    //

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int value = Get({42, 56});
    return 0;
}
```

I tried in Visual Studio 2010 but it doesn't break correctly with `key.myFirstField==42`

Can it be achieved ? If so, how ?

Comment: Works fine in VS 2015 Community Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works just fine with VS 2010 if you just create/initialize the object correctly:

```
int main()
{
    SpecificKey myKey;
    myKey.myFirstField = 41; // ...=42;
    myKey.mySecondField = 11;
    int value = Get(myKey);
    return 0;
}
```